# VB.Net - Is it possible for the appendAllText subroutine to not write all text if the program is halted?

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I'm writing a program that keeps track of database operations done while no internet is available in a text file. Once internet is available, the program uses the information in this file to execute all the operations made while there was no internet. I use the appendAllText method to write to the text file. I'm trying to anticipate every error that could possibly occur, and one of the things I'm worried about is, what if the program is halted while the appendAllText method is being executed (say maybe the program is forcibly closed or maybe the computer shuts off due to a powerout)? Could this lead to not all information being written to the text file or maybe even worse, corrupting the text file? I'm not sure how this method works at a low-level and I know this is a very unlikely scenario, but I just want to make sure no information about the database is ever lost as this could lead to pretty nasty errors.

Comment: Does it take such a long time to call AppendAllText for you? I try to write a lot of data and it does not take much time...

Comment: How much data are you writing at a time? Small amounts (eg five bytes at a time) are likely to deal with interruption much better than large amounts (eg 5Mb).

Comment: I write very small pieces at a time, at most 103 bytes at a time

Answer (score 3):

The best way to find out is to test it. I created the following sample program which appends 5 million lines:

```
var str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(1, 5000000).Select(i => $"This is line number {i}. This is some more content on this line."));
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\Test.txt", str);
```

When I interrupt the program before the end, there is simply no change to the file. If the file does not exist, it does not get created. Anyway, even with 5 million lines, the program is so fast, there is almost no chance of interruptions.